# How do I make a hotkey that mutes all sound when in a game

Tags: mute

How do I make a hotkey that mutes all sound when playing a game?

`nircmd` don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use AutoHotKey

```
SoundSet, NewSetting [, ComponentType, ControlType, DeviceNumber]

; BASIC EXAMPLES:
SoundSet, 50  ; Set the master volume to 50%
SoundSet +10  ; Increase master volume by 10%
SoundSet -10  ; Decrease master volume by 10%
SoundSet, 1, Microphone, mute  ; mute the microphone
SoundSet, +1, , mute  ; Toggle the master mute (set it to the opposite state)
SoundSet, +20, Master, bass  ; Increase bass level by 20%.
if ErrorLevel
    MsgBox, The BASS setting is not supported for MASTER.
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm

Comment: is there a program that just does this i dont know scripting